# Setting values from a class to Spring context file

Tags: java, spring

We usually define some beans with their properties in the Spring context file and write some setter methods in the class.

Let's say I want to do the opposite. I have a bean in the context file and want to declare some properties from the class, or initialize values of declared properties in the context from the class. How do I do that?

Comment: rephrase your question - it is unclear.

Comment: I, too, have no idea what you're trying to achieve.  The context file just gives you the ability to create a pool of (potentially) pre-created objects with defined properties... but nothing prevents you from further modifying the properties of those objects after retrieving them from the context.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. Bean factory post processors have the ability to alter or add to the context before spring fully initializers.

For more information please see the spring manual chapter for this: [Chapter 3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors)

Answer (score 1):

You could either the util Spring XML namespace [util:property-path](http://xsd-config-body-schemas-util-property-path) or a [PropertyPathFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPathFactoryBean.html) to reference a bean's property as value for a property.

Please note that the property you refer to does not need to be defined by Spring, it can be set in code, like your question suggests you want to do